# Jquery ui autocomplete with bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am creating a jquery-ui autocomplete list within a bootstrap layout and I'm with layout issues. My problem is that the list appears **transparent**, does not change color when the mouse is over the item, and are not respecting height. Can someone explain to me what is wrong? you need to use CSS in this case? I wanted to avoid having to modify the bootstrap to be able to reuse the code in other projects.

important: The autocomplete is inside of a bootstrap modal.

Here is the code I have done:

```
$(document).on("focus","#FormAlteracaoLocalizacao",function(e) {
    if ( !$(this).data("autocomplete") ) { // If the autocomplete wasn't called yet:
        $(this).autocomplete({             //   call it
            open: function(event) {
                $('.ui-autocomplete').css('height', 'auto');
                var $input = $(event.target),
                    inputTop = $input.offset().top,
                    inputHeight = $input.height(),
                    autocompleteHeight = $('.ui-autocomplete').height(),
                    windowHeight = $(window).height();

                if ((inputHeight + inputTop+ autocompleteHeight) > windowHeight) {
                    $('.ui-autocomplete').css('height', (windowHeight - inputHeight - inputTop - 20) + 'px');
                }
            },
              source: '../asp/source.asp',
              minLength: 2,
              select: function( event, ui ) {
                  $("#FormAlteracaoLocalizacao").val(ui.item.label);
                  $("#FormAlteracaotxtCdLocalizacao").val(ui.item.value);
                  return false;
              },
              focus: function( event, ui ) {
                  $("#FormAlteracaoLocalizacao").val(ui.item.label);
                  $("#FormAlteracaotxtCdLocalizacao").val(ui.item.value);
                  return false;
              },
              select: function( event, ui ) {
                  $("#situacaoimpressora").focus();
                  return false;
              },
            change: function(event, ui) {
                console.log(this.value);
                if (ui.item == null) {
                  $("#FormAlteracaoLocalizacao").val(FormAlteracaoLocalizacao);
                  $("#FormAlteracaotxtCdLocalizacao").val(FormAlteracaotxtCdLocalizacao);
                } 

            }
        });
        $(this).autocomplete( "option", "appendTo", ".form-horizontal" );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the jQuery-UI Autocomplete, then you'll need to use the associated jQuery-UI CSS for it in order for it to render correctly.

Comment: There isn't really any code to show - you just need to add a reference to the CSS file into your page. The CSS usually comes packaged with the jQuery-UI JavaScript files, and you'd put something like this in your page (adjust the path to where ever yours is located):

<link href="includes/jquery-ui-1.11.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: I see. Well, this is not the issue here, 'cause I'm including that. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: Use something like firebug to inspect the autocomplete results list in the DOM to see why it isn't having the CSS applied to it correctly. You can always add some additional CSS to fit your needs, such as setting a background color on the 'ul'.
It's hard to be more specific without a working example to see the problem.

Comment: that's hardly the answer right? Because I'm including the css and I don't see anything

Answer (score 0):

Just add a link to one of the built-in themes that comes with JQuery UI. Then your problems will be solved. e.g. link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/jqueryui/themes/cupertino/theme.min.css"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).